# Is it possible to make UNIQUE VALUE per KEY?

Tags: mysql

We have the table `Meeting` that stores all the meetings instances of users. Here, the primary key is `username`. When a meeting is being stored, we have to store `date`, which needs to be unique. Users can have only one meeting per day so it can't be more than one line of the same `date` and `username`. How can I apply this with the minimum of space?

Comment: A unique index on those columns should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_username_date ON Meeting(username,date);

note 1: where i call "unique_username_date" you can give the name that you want.

note 2: be careful with a case sensitive names, in this case on your table `Meeting`.

Comment: A pitty that schools have a lack of focus on INDEXES.
That's what I was looking for, thanks! 